# Nginx Cannot Find OpenSSL Development Headers

Tags: macos, path, nginx, homebrew

When I run: `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module` on my El Capitan Mac to install nginx, the terminal prints:

```
Checking for OpenSSL development headers...
  Found: no
```

But I am certain I have openssl installed. `which openssl` returns `/usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl` and `/usr/local/openssl/bin:` is the first entry in my $PATH. My questions are:

- Are the OpenSSL development headers included with the regular openssl install through homebrew?
- If they aren't, where should I download them from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to run `brew link openssl --force` in order to link the development headers from xcode to openssl. To clarify, I ran:

`brew install openssl
brew link openssl --force`

And it worked fine.

Comment: you should have upvoted + accepted answer on stackoverflow which pretty much said the same

Comment: I was told to place the question here instead... I would have, though, if the answer was posted here!